# Spring MVC MappingJackson2JsonView Collection Element Repeated

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

Given Person.java:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;

    // ...

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }
}
```

and Persons.java:

```
public class Persons implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final List<Person> persons;

    public Persons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }
}
```

When returning a JSON response for Persons, the "persons" element is repeated:

```
{
  "persons" : {
    "persons" : [ {
      "lastName" : "McCartney",
      "firstName" : "James",
      "middleName" : "Paul"
    }, {
      "lastName" : "Lennon",
      "firstName" : "John",
      "middleName" : "Winston"
    }, {
      "lastName" : "Starkey",
      "firstName" : "Richard",
      "middleName" : null
    }, {
      "lastName" : "Harrison",
      "firstName" : "George",
      "middleName" : null
    } ]
  }
}
```

How do I remove the extra element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is probably because you have an model attribute named `persons` which you are returning for `MappingJackson2JsonView` to convert to json:

`model.addAttribute("persons", personsType);`

There are two good fixes that I can think of:

1. To use `@ResponseBody` annotated controller methods instead, this way you can return persons and `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` would convert your type cleanly to json
2. If you want to continue with your approach, you can customize `MappingJackson2JsonView`with an additional flag to indicate that it has to extract value from the model before serializing to json - see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJackson2JsonView.html#setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel%28boolean%29)